# Mobile nav open close img

Tags: jquery, mobile, nav

I'm making a mobile Nav and what to include a plus and minus image to indicate when sub menus are opened or closed. I have the first part working fine when a user clicks on to open the sub menu the plus img changes to the minus img but now I can get it to change back when the sub menu is closed

here is the jquery

```
$(".listItem").click(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
 $(this).children('img').attr('src',"images/minus.png");
 })
```

Comment: Create a working fiddle in jsfiddle.net , context (html and css) is very important

Comment: Try something like `$(this).children('img').attr('src', function() { this.src == "images/minus.png" ? "images/plus.png" : "images/minus.png" });`

Comment: here is a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/w5pLcz8k/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like the comment from @regent and a simple ternary should work well.

An alternative option is to set the image as a background image in your css and then you can use the `toggleClass()` method to set the image.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/w5pLcz8k/4/)

**HTML: (replace your navOpen image with a span element that has a nav-icon class)**

```
<li class="listItem"><a href="#">Products</a><span class="nav-icon open"></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav-icon{
    float:right;
    padding:3px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nav-icon.open {
    background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519691-199_CircledPlus-20.png');
}
.nav-icon.close {
    background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/freecns-cumulus/16/519692-200_CircledMinus-20.png');
}
```

**jQuery: (find the nav-icon class within the listitem and toggle the open/close class on it**

```
 $('.listItem').click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.nav-icon').toggleClass('open close');
 });
```

Comment: P.S. in the demo I set the icon to position absolute to take it out of the flow of the document.  This will make sure that it doesn't affect the centering of your text.  Just remember you have to add position: relative to your list-item class then.